# Delphi always opens at the start-up with an empty form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, startup

Im using Delphi 7 and there is a annoying problem when Delphi 7 is started.
At the start of the application Delphi opens always with an empty form and an Unit1.pas where  only the header is written.
How I can reset this issue, so that Delphi is started WITHOUT any openings of forms and projects?

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: Run it (`delphi32.exe`) with `-np` parameter (-**n** o **p** roject maybe ?).

Comment: thanky you very much! :-))))))

Comment: Also, if you want the D7 IDE to re-open the project from your previous session, go to Tools | Environment Options. then on the Preferences tag, check the Autosave options Project Desktop

Comment: The `-np` parameter is still working even with Delphi 10.2.3 Tokyo (`bde.exe -p Delphi -np`)!